# Get the Height of a ScrollViewer in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I am having a trouble regarding ScrollViewer in my Windows Phone application (Universal App).

I have a ScrollViewer like the followring:

```
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="myScrollViewer" Grid.Row="1">
            <StackPanel>

                <TextBlock x:Name="myText"
                           Margin="12"
                           FontSize="30"
                           Text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           />        
                <Rectangle Height="140"
                           Width="400"
                           Fill="Blue"
                           Margin="12"
                           />
                <Rectangle Height="140"
                           Width="400"
                           Fill="Red"
                           Margin="12"
                           />                                        
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

Now I am trying to get the Height of this ScrollViewer. In code behind (inside the Constructor), I have tried:

```
double d = myScrollViewer.ActualHeight;

double d = myScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight;

double d = myScrollViewer.Height;
```

I have also tried other height relevant methods to get the Height of the ScrollViewer. But in every case, I got NULL or 0 in the d. Is there any way, that will return the Actual Height or Working Height of the ScrollViewer?

Comment: What does "In my Code at the cs end" mean? When are you trying to get the height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get ActualHeight of any framework element after Loaded event of Page. ActualHeight and ActualWidth are not set at the time of constructor or until the control is dynamically calculated/measured etc.